# Identifying what is causing High IO (Linux, Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, performance

> Your Linode, linodeXXXXX, has exceeded the notification threshold (1000) for disk io rate by averaging 1079.99 for the last 2 hours.

That's what I've been getting in my email for the past week, about 2-3 a day. I tried a few solutions, including finding [other](https://serverfault.com/questions/61510/linux-how-can-i-see-whats-waiting-for-disk-io) ServerFault posts on this issue, but they are not helping.

For example, I tried:

```
watch -n 1 "(ps aux | awk '\$8 ~ /D/  { print \$0 }')"
```

At various intervals, this will populate with an nginx process, or a kjournald process, etc but only for a few seconds. So it doesn't really help in figuring out what's causing it, it just tells me I keep getting high i/o.

Thus, the question becomes **How can I identify what is causing this high i/o usage?** Ideally, without starting at a process list for 6 hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install and run `iotop`. The topmost processes in the `iotop` display are very likely the ones generating the majority of the I/O requests in your VM.

Comment: @Bartek: you can also use the -o switch, which tells iotop to only show you the processes which are doing io.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great tool. I'll keep my eye on the display, but thus far nothing is really standing out (processes jumping around .. mySQL using some IO but only in 1-second spurts before going away from the list)

Comment: what about in the absence of iotop, which requires admin privileges?