# How is load average related to CPU utilization?

Tags: cpu-usage

I am facing a load average of > 3 since past 2 days. The CPU utilization is never above 40 % in all cases. Here are some screenshots of Server Density monitoring tool that I use.

[image]

The process snapshot at the highest peak, @ 0:00 is as follows:
[image]

And the process snapshot at the peak created at 12:00 is:
[image]

My question is, even though CPU utilization is not 100 %, why am I facing a high average?

PS: All snapshots are sorted by descending CPU utilization.

Comment: Bear in mind that when taking stefano's answer into account, a "high" load is subjective, if you have a machine with 4 cores a load of 3-4 isn't normally much to worry about.

Answer (score 4):

I assume this is due to a process being in a state of **uninterruptable sleep** ([[image] Sleep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_sleep#Uninterruptible_sleep)).

For a number of years now, the Linux kernel counts uninterruptable sleep towards load. This state is *usually* caused by a program waiting for **disk I/O**.

You can check if the high load correlates with I/O by watching the output of `ps aux`; look for a `D`in the Stat column, or see [[image] Linux - How can I see what's waiting for disk IO](https://serverfault.com/questions/61510/linux-how-can-i-see-whats-waiting-for-disk-io).

Comment: In my case there is no D in stat column... :(