# In absense of iotop which command is most appropriate for get i/o bounded process

Tags: performance, linux

Suggest me best way to list io bounded process. I know iotop is best way to get list but want any alternate option since my system showing a large number of D state process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Duplicated of: [Linux - How can I see what's waiting for disk IO](https://serverfault.com/questions/61510/linux-how-can-i-see-whats-waiting-for-disk-io) see that URL for a simple solution.

And you can enable disk I/O logging putting 1 into `/proc/sys/vm/block_dump`. then `tail -f /var/log/syslog` will give you reads and writes (process, pid, operation, blocks and device). Do not forget to return `/proc/sys/vm/block_dump` to zero when you're done.

Comment: It's the `kern.log` and/or `debug` file on Debian based distributions.

Answer (score 12):

You can check the IO usage of any process by looking at the `/proc/[pid]/io` file. Example:

```
$ cat /proc/1775/io
read_bytes: 4366336
write_bytes: 45056
cancelled_write_bytes: 229376
```

Comment: `iotop` now requires NET_ADMIN capability (or sudo/root) to be run, so this is a great alternative than using `setcap cap_net_admin+ep /usr/sbin/iotop` I guess.. thx!!

Comment: You must actually set the `cap_net_admin` on `python` for this to work.  `setcap cap_net_admin+ep /usr/bin/python2.7` for example.